# Assign specific variables from Backbone.Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

I'm fairly new to Backbone.JS and I'm having trouble understanding how to move data out of a collection and assigning it to a specific variable.

This is my setup which seems to be pretty standard.

```
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DataModel,
    url: 'assets/path_data.json'
  });

var dataCollection = new DataCollection()
      dataCollection.fetch({
        reset:true
      });

var ChoiceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var choiceModel = new ChoiceModel({
    froms: 'froms',
    a: 'omaha',
    b: 'to',
    c: 'phone_number',
    d: 'from_date',
    e: 'to_date',
    f: 'lon1',
    g: 'lat1',
    h: 'lon2',
    j: 'lat2',
  })
```

Then I set up my first view

```
var DataView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function(){
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.update);
    },
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to bring data out of the Model and use it in my render function. I've seen all the tutorials online and none of them assign the keys to specific variables. I have seen it done once, in a much simpler SPA and am hoping to replicate it.

This is how I would assign the keys in my render function.

```
render: function(){
      this.width = 1000
      this.height = 600
      this.svg = d3.select(this.el)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 1000)
        .attr('height', 600)

        //these do not work
        var a = choiceModel.get(a);
        var forms = dataCollection.get(froms);

        console.log(a)
        if (froms == a){
        function geolines (a,b,f,g,h,j){
        imageGroup.selectAll("image").data([0])
           .data(this.getData())
           .enter()
           .append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "dot.png")
            .attr("width", "10")
            .attr("height", "10")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.f, d.g][0]);
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.f, d.g][1]);
            })
        };
```

So you can see I'm trying to only include data where the 'froms' field matches 'omaha'. I don't think this should be a problem if I can assign the values from my collection. Really any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure there are some novice levels mistakes here, but I can't see them.

Also if this helps at all my json looks something like this.

```
[{"froms":"omaha","to":"kc","phone_number":7,"from_date":"6\/15\15/","to_date":"6\/15\15/","lon1":"36","lat1":"36","lon2":"36","lat2":"36"}]
```

Comment: var a = choiceModel.get(a); - here you put undefined variable a to choiceModel.get() method. In order to get value from model use string: choiceModel.get('a'), dataCollection.get('froms');

Comment: okay, that worked for the variable 'a', but not for the 'froms'. 'froms' is just now the string 'froms' so there are no matches. How can I query the values of 'froms'?

Comment: Oh, I might overlook something about Collections... Can you write, what returns dataCollection.get('froms')? Although I would check url 'assets/path_data.json', just in case.

Comment: dataCollection.get('froms') - returns the string 'froms',  dataCollections.get(froms) - returns undefined,      The url is totally fine

Comment: It would probably be a better practice to create a view for the model. The 'render()` function in the collection would then create separate views for each model and render those views. That will help you keep your collection and models distinct.

Comment: @stephenthomas you're totally right, I actually do this at the end of my script. I didn't include it here though. It makes keeping track of ones views incredibly easy!